# I added an overlay to go over the page when input is checked but now I can't close my menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying out adding an overlay to my page when the menu opens. Right now it works and a black overlay displays across the page but behind the menu due to its z index. However, I'm not unable to close the menu as the input is unable to be "unchecked". I also know my method of formatting this overlay is scuffed but I couldn't find a way to pretty up the way I'm aligning the overlay so I just set an insane negative left property to it.

```css
#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menu a {
  color: #212529;
  z-index: 3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
    background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0),
    opacity 0.55s ease;
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vh;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  left: -1950px;
  position: absolute;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
  z-index: 3;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 0;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 120vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-top: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: -100px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
        <div id="menuToggle">
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <div class="overlay">
            <!-- overlay when menu is open -->
          </div>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <ul id="menu">
            <ul class="category">
              <div class="rectangle-menu">
                <h1>Categories</h1>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <h3>Contract</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <hr>
              <ul>
                <h3>Crews</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Customer Lookup</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Estimates</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Folders and Documents</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Sharepoint</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>PowerApps</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>PowerBI Dashboard</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Grounds</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Maps and Outlines</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Outages</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Safety</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Storms</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <h3>Vehicles</h3>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Link</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add pointer-events:none to the overlay